# Port forwarding without IP address translation

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have a number of services that I'd like to run on unprivileged ports and use iptables to map standard privileged ports to the unprivileged ones (e.g. 80->8080).

I've been reading the iptables docs from netfilter.org and various tutorials and forums and every example I see translates the IP address in addition to forwarding the port (e.g. 10.0.1.1:80 -> 10.0.1.2:8080).

So my question is, I think, fairly simple.  Is it possible to do port forwarding **without** IP address translation?  So the iptables command might look something like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1:8080
```

If it is possible, is the above command correct (assuming an appropriate FORWARD rule accepts the connection)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your command is correct. The command presented by Arenstar is only valid for redirecting the traffic to localhost (127.0.0.1).

For more info, see `man iptables`. Look at `REDIRECT` paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Khaled.  Unfortunately I couldn't get iptables to do what I wanted, but I'll explore that further.  I just wanted to verify that what I was trying to do was at least possible.